# Android multipart entity image upload error

Tags: php, android, image, multipartentity

I am having a problem when uploading image to the server. When I upload it I get the HTTP 1.1 200 OK but then when I wath the response I see that the file is not uploaded because file of the same name already exists or not valid type. Here is my async task and php server code.

```
private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        if (bitmaps[0] == null)
            return null;
        setProgress(0);

        Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert Bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://mapped.guri.sk/imageUpload"); // server

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("myFile",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            Log.i("TAG", "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (response != null) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "response " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
                    try {
                        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } finally {

            }
        } finally {

        }

        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response: " + responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.uploaded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and this is php:

```
function imageupload(){
$target_dir = "/home/web/files.guri.sk/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    echo "http://files.guri.sk/".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
}
```

Comment: this is not correct way to send image to server

Comment: in above imageupload method you will online get image name not image data\

Comment: And how can I solve it ? I've found this code on https://github.com/DynamsoftRD/JavaHTTPUpload and do you mean the php method or java one ?

Comment: both you need to Convert image to string in your android and in your imageupload method covert it back to jpg format

Comment: search for image to string & String to image conversion

Comment: I've been looking for some other methods and multiple are doing this in similar way

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: I am trying your approach but now I have different error. Gonna post thsi to another question